# What are the current downsides of gradle?

Tags: gradle

What are the current downsides of Gradle? I have been researching different build tools but I haven't seen anything that seems to point out problems with Gradle as of October 2014. I have seen things a bit dated saying that Gradle users are on the bleeding edge. Is that still true or has Gradle reached decent point of maturity? (As far as I know, in terms of ide integration it might be more mature than others). Searching "why not use gradle" doesn't really help and "problems with gradle" shows people getting help (a plus). Most of what I have read were build tool comparisons and newer ones didn't list any flaws of Gradle.

Having not really used gradle except with libgdx projects I can't confirm issues presented in old comparisons still exist, but it seems like they don't.

The one thing I have seen that might be a problem is that it is "slow". If slowness is really an issue please explain how slow and what are the impacts.
Another somewhat reasonable downside is that people need to learn it to use it. To a person knowing how to use 0 tools this isn't really a problem and for others, it seems that Gradle is well documented and easy enough to learn.

I understand there are complications with switching and making sure the build still fully works so I am not asking what are the downsides of switching to gradle specifically but more generally why not use it now in a new project?

Looking for non opinionated reasons/problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently using Gradle as part of Android Studio, and its working decently. For me I had a HUGE headache getting started because the default settings of Gradle requires internet connection for the initial build (I assume it was for updates) and it fails to build if it can't make communication with the internet the first time. (so there are some Firewall issue you might need to work around) So the only 'Con' I have to add is that Firewalls can be a problem with initial set up of Gradle.

Comment: If that is the most significant downside somehow I will accept. I think I'll wait a bit for it to get more attention first though.